# Question about the resulting real voltage of pwm (pulse-width modulation)

Tags: voltage, current, pwm, frequency

I understand that pwm simply emits a voltage in either a LOW or HIGH state. But I read that for practical reasons, one can simply take the average voltage. If I would measure the voltage in practice, would that apply?

Comment: @Tyler so with a 50% duty cycle, I can half the max voltage?

Comment: sometimes; it depends on the application and circuit specifics.

Answer (score 2):

No, not in general:

If you measure fast enough, you'll see the high and lows.

Now, if you add a *low-pass filter* after the PWM unit, you will indeed filter out the changes, and "smoothen" the PWM to an average value.

So, whenever "I read somewhere that one can simply...", it's always worth asking which simplifications were made.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same.

Imagine you have a 1 ohm resistive heater, designed to run on 3 volts. You send 3 volts, E=IR 3V=3A*1ohm, EI=W 3V*3A=9 watts, and it is rated for 9 watts.  Happy dappy.  Instead, you send it 6 volts at 50% PWM.  Half the time, E=IR 6V=6A*1ohm, EI=W 6V*6A=36W.  An 18W average, which exceeds the heater's 9W rating.

Ditto ditto: LED good for 3A@3V (assuming magic LED).  Except LEDs are non-linear with a much sharper V-I curve. As it happens 6V gives 20A. EI=W, 6V*20A=120W, *half the time*, or 60W average.  Whoops!

OK, so you put a capacitor on there to smooth the rattle and nominally average 3V.  Except during the "on" time, the capacitor gulps up lots of current, and sustains the load at near 6V the rest of the time, effectively defeating the PWM.  You have to put some more stuff in there - limiting resistor, choke, something - to "tune" it so the smoothing keeps things near spec 3V@3A.  That assumes the load has a fixed characteristic like the heater.

If the load is dynamic, you'll need more active circuitry, and the best way is to dynamically tune the PWM to *other than* 50%, and now we're talking a switching constant-voltage or constant-current supply.  if the goal is to divide the input voltage by exactly 50%, it could certainly use the input voltage as a pilot signal for the correct output voltage.

Answer (score 0):

PWM works by varying the duty-cycle (let's call it D) of a square wave (with 0 as low and some max value as high), as you know. It can be shown fairly easily that the average value of that square wave is proportional to D.

> ... for practical reasons, one can simply take the average voltage.

They are also theoretical reasons, because the average value is what the system being controlled is sensible to. That's the whole point of PWM: controlling an analog system using a digital signal without a complex DAC scheme. A digital system like a microcontroller can easily generate PWM signals with adjustable duty cycle, therefore that's an easy way to control a system.

To be more specific: when you design a PWM control system correctly, you set the PWM frequency so high that the system being controlled cannot follow the rapid variation of the PWM signal, hence it acts, by its own inertia, as a low-pass filter. Therefore the system being controlled turns out to react only to the average value of the PWM, which varies much more slowly than the instantaneous value of the PWM signal itself (that's a requirement of PWM: duty cycle variations should be slow compared to the period of the PWM signal).

In other words, the intrinsic inertia of the system behaves as a low-pass filter, which, in turn, extracts only the DC component of the PWM, i.e. its average value.

> If I would measure the voltage in practice, would that apply?

It depends how you measure the voltage. If you use an oscilloscope, you'll see the exact PWM waveform (but a fairly modern, cheap, digital scope can calculate its average value and display it on screen). If you use a simple voltmeter it depends on the PWM frequency and its measurement method.

Bottom line: for a correctly designed PWM control scheme, what really matters is the average value of the PWM signal, both from a practical and from a theoretical POV.